# SmtpClient sends mail from windows application but fails in ASP.NET / MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, smtpclient

Hi I am getting a funny error. I am able to send email if I use windows application but the same code when run as part of ASP.NET / MVC application throws SendMessage error saying - `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

The code I am using is:

```
 using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage("from@my.com", "t0@my.com"))
                {
                    message.CC.Add("cc@my.com");
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    message.Subject = "Test subject");
                    message.Body = "Test Body";
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Host = "abc.com";
                    client.Port = 25;
                    client.Send(message);
                }
```

Can someone suggest what is wrong here.

Thanks,
A

Comment: sounds like your webserver cant contact the mail server..

Comment: What may be the resolution of this issue.

Comment: Getting access granted through firewalls usually ..

Comment: But since it is working in the windows application that means there is no firewall issue else even that wont work.

Comment: actually it doesnt - if you have something like zonealarm running..

Answer (score 0):

> Gets or sets the name or IP address of the host used for SMTP transactions.

as [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.host(v=vs.110).aspx) said. maybe you can't use "abc.com" as host.

for gmail may be it should be

```
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

it works for me

```
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage("from@my.com", "t0@my.com"))
{
    message.CC.Add("cc@my.com");
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Subject = "Test subject";
    message.Body = "Test Body";
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.Port = 25;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourEmail", "Password");
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: The host name is correct since it works in the windows application. But why does it fail in the browser application. Also it works on gmail for me too.

Comment: I am not sure about that. But you need an existing IP address of host for email sending